# Data Structure Parallel Add Serial Remove Needed

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, parallel-processing, gpgpu

I'm working on a dynamically branching particle system on the GPU.  I need a parallel data structure with the following properties:

1. One thread must be able to remove elements one by one, in constant time.  The element returned isn't important to the algorithm--just so long as *some* element is returned when nonempty.  For extra awesomeness, change to any number of threads.
2. Any number of threads must be able to add elements to the data structure in constant time.  Note that some locking is allowed, (and necessary) but it must still scale with no relation on the number of threads.  I.e., more threads shouldn't slow it down.

Basic synchronization primitives (mutexes, semaphores), and anything that can be implemented using them, are available.

I had toyed with the idea of a linked list, but this violates condition two (since adding would be O(m) for m threads, since locking must be taken into consideration).  I'm not sure such a data structure exists--but I thought I would ask.

Comment: Do you need the elements to be ordered? If not, you could use a hash table and have a mutex at the hash level (so you'd only have locking if there is a hash collision). Edit: you can take it a step further and use a lock-free hash table such as [this one](https://www2.cs.fau.de/EN/teaching/WS2007/ParAlg/lockfreeHashTable.pdf).

Comment: @smocking How do you find the element to remove from a hash table? I expect just finding the next non-empty bucket would be rather slow. Or would you put some data structure on top of it?

Comment: @ErikP. You can iterate to the next key in O(1) in most implementations, but the order of the keys will not be defined, i.e. it will not be the order in which you inserted the elements. If you need to preserve insertion order, you could use a red-black tree or B-tree; those have log(N) worst case complexity for the operations you describe and locking doesn't get out of hand either.

Comment: The elements can be unordered, and the remove operation can remove _any random element_ (so no, insertion order is unimportant).  An amortized hash collision is okay, probably.  I'll look into GPU hash tables further.

Comment: @smocking I see - thanks! I was talking about the non-ordered case of the OP. I guess you can make this work (at least in an amortized sense) by ensuring you always have O(N) entries in your hash table by growing and shrinking your array of buckets, and then just go to the next non-empty bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about how you want your data organized (sorted? FIFO? LIFO?) I'm. Or sure whether I can give you an exact answer.  However, what you're describing sounds like the definition of a lock-free structure.  Lock-free implementations of stacks and queues exist, which do support O(1) insertions and deletions even when there are a lot of threads modifying the structure concurrently.  They're usually based on atomic test-and-set operations.

If locks are okay and you just want a highly-concurrent data structure that's sorted, consider looking into concurrent skip lists, which provide O(log n) sorted insertion and deletion with multiple active threads.

Hope this helps!

Comment: To clarify: the insertion/remove order is irrelevant (in fact, it's more like a "set" than anything ordered).  How about the hash table mentioned in the comments above?  The ideal algorithm would have O(n) space and O(1) insert and remove--even when _m_ threads are reading and writing.